# How can I convert this java filter into a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have the below java streams function, but I would like to use a PostgreSQL query instead to retrieve the same information, perform the filter and if possible collect to a list. I would like to write a query in the repo layer such as `@Query("")` but unsure what to write. Table name is `pop_responder` and column name is `pop_registrants`.

```
    public List<PopResponderDao> getAllPopResponders() {
    return popResponderRepository
        .findAll()
        .stream()
        .filter(responderDao -> responderDao.getPopRegistrationDaos().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

`PopRegistrationDaos` is of type `Collection<PopRegistrationDao>`. Repository layer uses JPA:

```
public interface PopResponderRepository extends JpaRepository<PopResponderDao, Long> {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for using stream to interact with database as of now.

If you only need to filter your data you can using JPQL queries.
A `filter` is basically a `WHERE` clause in JPQL.

```
SELECT p FROM PopResponderDao p where p.popRegistrationDaos IS NOT EMPTY
```